# Starting an upstart task - Unknown job error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos6, upstart

I have written an upstart task that I am trying to start on my CentOS 6 and Ubuntu boxes.  I placed my upstart task in /etc/init/sidekiq.conf

But when I run...

```
start sidekiq
```

or

```
service start sidekiq
```

As root, I get...

```
start: Unknown job: sidekiq
```

My upstart file is as below...

```
# /etc/init/sidekiq.conf - Sidekiq config for Ubuntu's Upstart

description "Sidekiq Background Workers"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]

env RAILS_ENV = 'qa'
env app = 'myapp'

setuid deploy
setgid deploy

respawn
respawn limit 3 30

#exec bundle exec sidekiq -e qa03

cd /srv/www/${app}
exec start-stop-daemon --start bundle exec sidekiq -q mailer -q default -L log/sidekiq.log -e ${RAILS_ENV}
```

Why is it not starting? I thought running start sidekiq should run the task?

Answer (score 1):

`cd` is not an Upstart stanza. Just add a script section with the cd command. Also, your `env` stanzas should look like so: `env app='myapp'` (note the deletion of whitespace around the "=").

You can also just delete the "start-stop-daemon --start" portion, you do not need it (although the stuff before and after it you do need).